# A person with poor rational abilities

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I want to describe a person in my article with the following characteristics:

- Not good at grasping in studies.
- Doing a poor job just because he fears going out and expanding/trying better jobs.

Please suggest a word(s) that would mean both of the above.

Comment: I meant, this guy is not willing to go for a better job due to his low-confidence. Poor guy, he was not good in studies/sports.

Comment: That comment better be in the question body.

Comment: We also have Cognitive Sciences Q&A http://cogsci.stackexchange.com

Comment: He has got "avoidant personality disorder"(type 3 personality disorder).you might also call him a "shy person".

Answer (score 1):

Someone not good in school or not good at understanding ideas can be called "**intellectually challenged**", and someone who doesn't want to go out looking for a better and more responsible job can be called a "**[hypengyophobic](http://www.fearofstuff.com/humans/fear-of-responsibility/)**". I can't think of a single nice word that includes both meanings. "Moron" comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

The two descriptions are completely distinct from one another and I can't think of a single word that describes both. For the first one, I would suggest:

> **slow-witted**
>       *adjective*
>       slow to understand, think, or learn; stupid: the slow-witted interviewer
>       failed to pounce on his remarks.

Or simply *slow*. As in *he's a bit slow*.

And for the second one, I would suggest:

> **unambitious** |ˌənamˈbiSHəs|
>       *adjective*
>       not motivated or driven by a strong desire or determination to succeed.
>       • (of a plan or piece of work) not involving anything new, exciting, or demanding.

*Definition source: NOAD*

Answer (score 0):

> **underachiever**
>       *noun*
>       someone (such as a student or athlete) who does not perform as well or work as hard as he or she can

It is commonly used in pop culture, Bart Simpson is refereed to numerous times as an underachiever. This word is good to describe the quality of outcome (or accurately the consistency of a less than ideal outcome) without speaking to the cause.